# How to check used Module or Object name for the Salesforce report?

Tags: api, reporting, etl

I have a report which is about Quotes in Salesforce created by one of the user, now I am trying to pull that report data using one of ETL tool talend using SOAP API's.
But the issue is report are not visible when I retrieve the modules from salesforce , I can see one module with "Quotes" but that has 0 repords.

I asked them also but they are not aware of this, so my question is how can we check the Module or Object name from the salesforce report?